# selenium webdriver module has no FirefoxProfile() attribute

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Ok, I am trying to set my browsers proxy file, I have everything configured correctly but not entirely sure why I keep getting this error.

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http', "173.255.117.227")
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', 7779)
profile.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('whatismyipaddress.com')
time.sleep(4)
driver.close()
```

This is the error I am getting -

```
========== RESTART: C:/Users/The Family/Desktop/FireFoxProxyBot.py ==========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/The Family/Desktop/FireFoxProxyBot.py", line 4, in <module>
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FirefoxProfile'
>>>
```

Comment: Titles are there to help other people with the same problem find a question whose answers might help them (and, secondarily, to help people find questions they have particularly applicable knowledge towards answering). The original one on this question does neither; in the future, please try to build a title to be as specific as possible, so someone else with the same problem can identify that their problem matches yours from the title alone. (I've tried to edit in a better title as an example).

Comment: Ok, tyvm, I think thats the most specific I can be. My apologize, I will be editing the titles for the most detail from now on. Would you happen to know why I am receiving this error. Its correct according to the usage in the selenium documentary.

Comment: FirefoxProfile is present in webdriver when on the macports build of selenium 2.21.2, which is what I have at hand, so I don't get that issue. Could you specify the exact version you're using, any pertinent details on where you downloaded it from, &c?

Comment: I used the pip install selenium, and I believe its the current version. - I am using Python 3.44

Comment: Hmm. If I create a new Python 3.5 virtualenv and run `pip install selenium` in that, I get 2.53.6 -- and it still has a FirefoxProfile class. What do you get if you `print(webdriver.__file__)`? If it points to your `site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py`, and you look at the file, it should contain `from .firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile  # noqa` -- does it?